# Python, os.popen, pyinstaller, windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, mac-address

I am trying to run the following bit of code as part of a larger python program to get my mac address:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"):
        if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'):
            maccode = line.split(':')[1].strip().replace('-', ':')
            break
else:
    for line in os.popen("/sbin/ifconfig"):
        if line.find('Ether') > -1:
            maccode = line.split()[4]
            break
```

When I run this code in python 3.5 as part of a .py program it works fine. When I compile my program using pyinstaller into an exe and I get to the following line it fails

```
for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"):
```

Any ideas on how I can get around this problem? I have done some reading and I think I could use "subprocess" but I have been unsuccessful in creating the alternative line. Any help would be great.

Comment: What error message appears when running the executable?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Never mind though. I found the problem was to do with permissions. I needed to run the program as administrator and then it worked fine.